# Is there a way to style an email tag that becomes a premade HTML <a> link?

Tags: html, html-email

I'm working on creating an email notification within helpdesk software, Sysaid.  The software uses **HTML markup** for its email notifications in combination with email tags starting with $ to act as stand-ins for information submitted within the software.  The below tags

```
$Approve
$Deny
$LinkToSubTab
```

should all turn into links.  and while they do- the first two become pre-wrapped hyperlinks that come with the `<a href="example URL">example text</a>` and the last one is just a normal link.  Ideally I want to make them all act as buttons, but putting the pre-wrapped $tag breaks the html of all the ways of implementing buttons or styling I've tried.  I've found that I can change stuff like the font- size of said hyperlinks by adding the `<font size=50>` tag before the link, but haven't had success yet with attaching stylings or text decorations to said links.  To be clear, this isn't about the Sysaid software itself but rather finding a way to style a hyperlink that comes premade from an email tag, from outside of the tag. the tag `$Approve` becomes an `<a href='link'>Text<a>` that's premade, and attempting to fit it into a button or text decoration (in my limited understanding) breaks the element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to style a premade hyperlink for an email template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65688964/is-there-a-way-to-style-a-premade-hyperlink-for-an-email-template)

Comment: There are no answers on the previous question.  It was closed before edits requested on it could be applied.

Comment: You can edit a closed question just fine. There is absolutely no excuse to repost it.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never worked with the software you're describing, if you want to style an HTML hyperlink you could try using CSS to apply styles based on a wrapper element:

```css
/*This will directly effect the a tag*/
.hyperlink-wrapper a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="hyperlink-wrapper">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Not for sure how you want them styled but you can do a lot with CSS. Here are two basic examples:

```css
.custom-link a {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 32px;
  /* Remove Underline */
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.button a {
  padding: 16px;

  /* Remove Underline */
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: white;
  background-color: #60ca60;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.button a:hover {
  background-color: #57b357;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-link">
  <a href="#">Click Me</a>
</div>

<br><br>

<div class="button">
  <a href="#">Button</a>
</div>
```

The way the code is structured, adding a `$Approve` in place of the `a` tag won't break it. If you need help putting this code in your email, want different styles, or need inline hyperlinks (this will break the paragraph) just comment below.